# Need Help on Ubuntu and Bigbluebutton

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, bigbluebutton

I am new on Linux Ubuntu server.

I tried to install Big Blue Button on Ubuntu 14.04 server by followed the guide at http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html

I got this error when I tried to do a clean Restart (step 9):

```
root@ubuntu:~# bbb-conf --clean
# Nginx: BigBlueButton appears to be disabled
- no symbolic link in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/bigbluebutton to     /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton
cat: /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton: No such file or directory
# Tried to check server_name in
#    /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton
# but value is empty.
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Reza

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [ubuntu.SE].

Answer (score 0):

> cat: /etc/nginx/sites-available/bigbluebutton: No such file or
>   directory

Check the output from earlier steps when installing BigBlueButton itself, specifically the installation of packages.

You very likely received an error from one of the package installs (likely either bbb-web or bbb-client).